# Combining two character variables into a character list in R to be used in ggplot

Tags: r

I am making over 200 stacked bar graphs to illustrate plant species change over time. I need to make a named character list similar to this:

```
species_color_code <- c("ALDE" = "CORAL", "BRJA" = "BLUE", 
"BRSQ2" = "POWDERBLUE")
```

This list is used in `ggplot` to assign each plant species a specific color.

I have already assigned a random color to each species name (i.e ALDE, BRJA, etc) in a previous step and saved to a .csv file for future use. I have just over 400 plant species that each have a random color assigned, so making the above list by hand is going to be time consuming.

My problem is that I have not figured out how to pull the species name and color name from the CSV file, add a "=" and then  place them all into a `c()` function to make the correct list for `ggplot`.

```
> species_color_file
    Species   Color_Samples
1      PASM    lightsalmon2
2     PSSP6   darkturquoise
3      AGCR           snow2
4     ELLAL   antiquewhite4
5     ELTR7         tomato1
```

I have looped through each row of the .csv file found each Species Name and corresponding Color. No matter how I `paste()`, `c()`, etc. I can't make them work/match what is needed for the plot.

```
species_color_codes <- as.character(list())
for(j in 1:nrow(species_color_file)){
    species_color_names <- paste(species_color_file$Species[j],
    species_color_file$Color_Samples[j], sep = "=", collapse = "")
    species_color_codes <- c(species_color_codes, species_color_names, 
    sep = ",")
}
```

What I get:

```
> species_color_codes
                                          sep                                               sep 
     "PASM=lightsalmon2"                      ","    "PSSP6=darkturquoise"                      "," 
                                              sep                                               sep 
            "AGCR=snow2"                      ","    "ELLAL=antiquewhite4"                      ","
```

What i need :

```
> species_color_codes <- c("ALDE" = "CORAL", "BRJA" = "BLUE", "BRSQ2" = "POWDERBLUE")
> species_color_codes
        ALDE         BRJA        BRSQ2 
     "CORAL"       "BLUE" "POWDERBLUE"
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
species_color_codes <- species_color_file$Color_Samples
names(species_color_codes) <- species_color_file$Species
```

You are attempting to create a named vector - that is, a vector where each element has a name. In your first example, you don't need the quotation around the species, as these will just be the character names.

Example:

```
> species_color_codes <- c(PASM  =  "lightsalmon2",
+ PSSP6 =  "darkturquoise",
+ AGCR  =         "snow2",
+ ELLAL =  "antiquewhite4",
+ ELTR7 =        "tomato1")
> species_color_codes
  PASM           PSSP6            AGCR           ELLAL           ELTR7 
"lightsalmon2" "darkturquoise"  "snow2" "antiquewhite4"       "tomato1"
```

You've stored the names in a data file and then read them back in. Thus, all you need to do is store the colors in a new object and then assign the species names to the names property of that object.